# Interop Domino Get Navigator elements

Tags: c#, interop-domino

now I am working with notes database. I used interop.domino dll to interact with Notes database. I can get almost design elements of a note database by exporting it to dxl file.

But when I try to get navigator elements, I met a trouble. I got navigator's information is encode by something like Base64.

I don't know how can I get navigator's information such as: hostpost button, image, etc.

Comment: can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigators were introduced in Notes 4.0, but have been for all intents and purposes deprecated since the release of Notes 5.0 - in 1999.

They never got full support in DXL.